# image gallery media query

Tags: css, slider, gallery

Is it possible to setup an image gallery, for instance WOWSlider, so that the images will load from a css media query?
this way i can load a smaller image for a smartphone and a bigger image for the desktop.

Comment: There are dozens of possible solutions for your issue. Search for "responsive images" on Google and you'll get some idea. Do you want to render images server-side on the flight? Serve a pre-made collection? What language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest giving each slide a unique ID and then setting a background image for each slide. This way you can load different background images using media queries